# The "bootstrap" tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

Currently, `bootstrap` can refer either to either  [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) (the CSS framework), or [bootstrapping](/questions/tagged/bootstrapping).  Thus, [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) is ambiguous.

Can people help me clean up this tag so it refers to either?

Comment: There seems to be a third option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework+bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

I've gone ahead and retagged the 30 or so [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) questions that were really about [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap).

[I made the](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=106224) [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag, so this is something I should be doing regularly anyway :)

Comment: This has annoyed me recently (as well as the [tag:prototype] tag being used for [tag:prototypejs]) so I've gone ahead and retagged another 30 or so from March 16th onwards. I think I got all of them between then and today. I'll trust that you got all the ones before that date :)