# "Bootstrap" tag, again

Tags: discussion, tags

In march 2012 [it was noticed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125823/172431) that [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) was being incorrectly used for [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) questions but the situation has only gotten worse. In the questions added since then, those that are tagged [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) and are not about the twitter-bootstrap framework seem a minority.

Time for another cleanup?

Perhaps give up and retag the other questions from [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) to [bootstrapping](/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) and make [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) a synonym for [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)?

Comment: there h as been a 150 rep user flooding the review queue with these `bootstrap` to `twitter-bootstrap` changes.

Comment: I'll look at it tomorrow if nobody else has done the retag already. Not sure about the synonyms just yet.