# Answers are not always reindexed correctly when question tags are changed

Tags: bug, search, tag-search

Trying to [help cleaning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/162023/172431) the [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) list I tried searching for `[bootstrap] twitter` and the description matches what I want:

"results found containing **twitter** tagged with [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap)"

But I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13648514/422353) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13933000/422353) questions as part of the results. Those two have "twitter" in the title but they are tagged [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) instead of [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap).

Now, those questions were tagged with [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) but I changed them a few days ago.

Comment: You probably want to add `is:question` to your query, but it does look like there's something wrong with search thinking those answers still belong to a question with the [tag:bootstrap] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers for this question didn't get re-indexed when the change happened.  It seems to be a very rare occurrence, but I'll look into it as time allows next week, then fix these up once I track down the root cause.